# How to download player.vdocipher video content?

Tags: python, java

I have this url: https://player.vdocipher.com/playerAssets/1.x/vdo/embed/index.html#otp=20************ When I clicked to download, I could not download it. I tried to make it work.

I need to access it, but how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since VdoCipher provides DRM encryption for Videos, you cannot download it unless you have a hack.

Comment: okay bro understandable.